# short pressure of listview in a context menu

Tags: android, listview

But, I have a question. How to represent context menu for short pressure in listview or textview? Here my source code, all that wrote. But for me long pressure goes out context menu.

```
public class Day extends ListFragment  { 
    @Override 
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {       
      super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState); 

     DayAdapter myListAdapter = new DayAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.text_fragment, names); 
      setListAdapter(myListAdapter); 
    } 

    @Override 
     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
      Bundle savedInstanceState) {       
       View rootView =inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview, container, false); 
       ListView lv = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.list); 
       lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() { 

        @Override 
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, 
                int position, long id) { 
            registerForContextMenu(view); 
                        } 

       public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) { 
            menu.setHeaderTitle("Hello"); 
            menu.setHeaderIcon(R.drawable.up); 
            menu.add(0, 0, 0, "Item One"); 
            menu.add(0, 1, 0, "Item Two"); 
        } 
    }); 
   return rootView; } }
```

Comment: Sorry i really dont understand..what are you asking? What is "pressure"?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `openContextMenu()` inside your onItemClick method.

```
@Override 
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) { 
    registerForContextMenu(view);
    openContextMenu(view);
}
```

See:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#openContextMenu(android.view.View)

Comment: I wrote, but for me does not open a context menu.